# How to parse two strings, and keep track of their coordinates in python?

Tags: python, string, iteration, coordinates

I would like to simultaneously parse a pair of strings in python, and keep track of their coordinates (when skipping `"X"`). Please let me know if I could clarify better:

There are two strings, `string1` and `string2`, which randomly contain the character `X`. I am jointly parsing and analysing the characters in these strings (which are the same length):

```
string1 = "RANDXMSTRINXHERE"
string2 = "XLSORAXDOXSTRING"
```

There are also variables initialized to integers representing "start coordinates" for these strings (in a different coordinate system of course):

```
string1_start = 5
string2_start = 12
```

The X characters should be ignored. I would like to "keep track of where the X's fall" in terms of these two strings with the rule that, if `string1` contains a character which is not `X`, then iterate the variable `string1_start+=1`. Simultaneously, when `string2` contains a container not `X`, then iterate the variable `string2_start+=1`. This is simple enough to do:

```
string1_start = 5    ## starting coordinate for string1
string2_start = 12   ## starting coordinate for string2

string1 = "RANDXMSTRINXHERE"
string2 = "XLSORAXDOXSTRING"

for i, j in zip(string1, string2):
    if i != 'X' and j != 'X':
        string1_start += 1
        string2_start += 1
    elif i != 'X' and j == 'X':
        string1_start += 1
    elif i == 'X' and j != 'X':
        string2_start += 1
```

Given that logic, I'm struggling to figure out how to "record" what the coordinate of `string2` is when `string1` is at coordinate 9 or 17. That is, as soon as `string1_start == 9`, cache the result of `string2_start` and as soon as `string1_start == 17`, cache the result of `string2_start`.

For example, this will not work:

```
coord9 = 0
coord17 = 0
for i, j in zip(string1, string2):
    if i != 'X' and j != 'X':
        string1_start += 1
        string2_start += 1
        if start1_start == 9:
            coord9 = string2_start
        if start1_start == 17:
            coord17 = string2_start    
    elif i != 'X' and j == 'X':
        string1_start += 1
        if start1_start == 9:
            coord9 = string2_start
        if start1_start == 17:
            coord17 = string2_start  
    elif i == 'X' and j != 'X':
        string2_start += 1
        if start1_start == 9:
            coord9 = string2_start
        if start1_start == 17:
            coord17 = string2_start
```

How could I incorporate that logic into the above? Should I be keeping track of the coordinates with a different data structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify your index increment logic by adding `i != 'X'` which will evaluate to `True` or `False` that added will act as `1` or `0`.

```
string1_idx = 5    ## starting coordinate for string1
string2_idx = 12   ## starting coordinate for string2

string1 = "RANDXMSTRINXHERE"
string2 = "XLSORAXDOXSTRING"
coord9 = cord17 = ''

for i, j in zip(string1, string2):
    string1_idx += i != 'X'
    string2_idx += j != 'X'

    if string1_idx == 9:
        cord9 = string2_idx
    if string2_idx == 17:
        cord17 = string1_idx

print(cord9, cord17)  # -> 16, 11
```

Comment: The syntax `string1_idx += i != 'X'` is the same as `if i != 'X': string1_idx += i`?

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the help. I see now why I was getting so confused.